# get all data from jquery table and insert to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to get data from my table and insert into database. The problem is when I'm trying to insert into db,only the first data goes into database. I've searched a lot of questions and even asked here before but I don't really understand how the process goes. My table looks like this, [image: mytable]

and this is my html script

```
 <table id="list4" class="table" width="777" border="0">
                 <thead> <tr><th>Language</th><th>Spoken</th><th>Writen</th>  </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                   <tr class="list4_var">
                     <td><select id="list4_Language_0" name="list4_Language_0" style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
            <option value="Malay">Malay</option>
            <option value="English">English</option>
            <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
            <option value="Tamil">Tamil</option> 
          </select>
              </td>
                    <td><select id="list4_Spoken_0" name="list4_Spoken_0" style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
            <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
            <option value="Good">Good</option>
            <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
            <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
            <option value="Very Bad">Very Bad</option>
          </select></td>
                <td><select name="list4_Writen_0" id="list4_Writen_0" style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
            <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
            <option value="Good">Good</option>
            <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
        <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
        <option value="Very Bad">Very Bad</option>
          </select></td>
        <td class="del_area04"><button type="button" class="list4_del btn btn-danger" style="float:left;">Delete</button></td></tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>
```

and this is my php code which i tried to get all the data and insert into db

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var table = $("#list4 table tbody");
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            language = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            spoken = $tds.eq(1).text(),
            writen = $tds.eq(2).text();
            });
</script>

$s_language = ($_POST['list4_Language_0']);
$s_spoken = ($_POST['list4_Spoken_0']);
$s_writen = ($_POST['list4_Writen_0']);
$studentId = ($_SESSION['student']);

// attempt insert query execution
   if ( $insert = $mysqli->query ( "INSERT INTO tbllanguage (language,   spoken, writen, studentId) VALUES ('$s_language', '$s_spoken', '$s_writen', '$studentId')"))
   {
?> 
        <script>alert('Language saved ...')
        window.location='myResume.html'</script>
<?php
   }
}
```

Comment: since you are going to insert multiple rows in single submit, declare your field names as array like this:`list4_Language_0[]`.and do some google on ajax.

Comment: when i tried put an array inside the name i got alert jquery error..is there any other way to solve this?